# Задача на массивы. Не могу решить

Tags: java

Задание такое:
1. Создать массив на 15 целых чисел.
2. Ввести в него значения с клавиатуры.
3. Пускай индекс элемента массива является номером дома, а значение - число жителей, проживающих в доме.
Дома с нечетными номерами расположены на одной стороне улицы, с четными - на другой. Выяснить, на какой стороне улицы проживает больше жителей.
4. Вывести на экран сообщение: "В домах с нечетными номерами проживает больше жителей." или "В домах с четными номерами проживает больше жителей."

Примечание:
дом с порядковым номером 0 считать четным.

Вот такой код я написал:

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int [] number = new int [15];
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    int even = 0;
    int odd = 0;

    int b = number.length;
    for (int i=0; i<b; i++)
    {String a = reader.readLine();
        int resident = Integer.parseInt (a);
        int c = resident % 2;
        if (c==0) {
            even ++;
        }
        else {
            odd ++;
        }
        number [i] = resident;
    }
    if (even>odd)
        System.out.println("В домах с чётными номерами проживает больше жителей.");
    else
         System.out.println("В домах с нечетными номерами проживает больше жителей.");

    }
      }
```

И вот какую ошибку выводит валидатор (см. рис. 1)
[image: Рис. 1]

Comment: Ты проверяешь на четность не номер дома, а количество жителей в нем и складываешь не количество жителей а что-то другое.

Comment: на javarush есть специальный форум для помощи, вам лучге спросить там. Тут таки не обучающий портал.

Comment: tym32167, во-первых - я не стал бы засорять эфир если бы мне там помогли, а во-вторых -  почему я не могу воспользоваться этим ресурсом? Зачем же мне он тогда нужен

Comment: Эникейщик, спасибо за дельный ответ. Потом проверю

Comment: я вам не запрещаю пользоваться этим сайтом. Если бы я был против вашего вопроса, я бы голосовал за его закрытие, но вы можете поглядеть - никто не хочет ваш вопрос сейчас закрывать. Я вам только подсказал, где вам скорее всего ответят, так как сам там недавно учился (дошел пока до 15 уровня)

Comment: tym32167, а  я малость застрял там на 7-м уровне. Задачи не решаются. Компилятор ругается. Вопросы остаются без ответа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный вариант решения проходит валидатор:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {                                                  
            BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));                                                  
            int[] arr = new int[15];                                                  
            int even = 0;                                                  
            int odd = 0;                                                  
            for(int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {                                                  
                arr[x] = Integer.parseInt(rdr.readLine());                                                  
                if(x == 0 || x % 2 == 0) even += arr[x];                                                  
                else odd += arr[x];                                                  
            }                                                  
            String result = (even > odd) ? "В домах с четными номерами проживает больше жителей." :                                                  
            "В домах с нечетными номерами проживает больше жителей.";                                                  
            System.out.println(result);                                                  
        }
```